# Formula parse error in Google Sheets - using IF statement along with multiple 'OR' statements

Tags: google-sheets, formula, parse-error

Trying to create a spreadsheet to keep track of levels on a game (brawlhalla), and when trying to create a formula, I kept coming across the error stated in the title

The formula is as follows:
=IF((J2="Ada") OR(K2 = "Ada") OR(L2 = "Ada") OR(M2 = "Ada") Or(N2 = "Ada") OR(O2 = "Ada"),"Y","N")

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I can see where you're coming from because in most programming languages (including Ada?) putting OR between two expressions works, but not in an Excel or Google Sheets spreadsheet formula, you have to put

```
=if(OR(J2="Ada",K2="Ada",L2="Ada",M2="Ada",N2="Ada",O2="Ada"),"Y","N")
```

If it's a continuous range, there are shorter ways of doing it like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Ada",J2:O2,0)),"Y","N")
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(J2:O2,"Ada"),"Y","N")
```

The nearest equivalent to the original formula (since there are no logical operators) is

```
=IF((J2="Ada")+(K2="Ada")+(L2="Ada")+(M2="Ada")+(N2="Ada")+(O2="Ada"),"Y","N")
```

which exploits the fact that a TRUE value equates to 1 when used in an arithmetical expression.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful (btw Ada is not a language it is a piece of data)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. BTW my comment about Ada was just a little joke, I know it's just a piece of data but it also happens to be the name of a programming language.